# What's the right way of configuring the path to a sqlite database for my servlets to use?

Tags: java, servlets, initialization

I'm using SQLite as my database, and I'm a little bit confused about how I'd configure the path to it. Basically, I have a static String in one of my classes ( which, after initialization turns to something like this ):

```
private static String DATABASE = "db/my.db";
```

The folder `db` is located directly under `WebContent`, so, to get access to it, I need to use a `ServletContext`'s `getRealPath` method. To use that, I need access to a servlet, and since I'm not sure which servlet will be the first one to be called, I need to perform a check in all of my requests to see if the database has been set, and if it hasn't then set it. I think there should be a better way of doing this. 
For the moment, I created an abstract class which inherits from HttpServlet, adds 2 methods, a `getImpl` and a `postImpl` ( both abstract ), and my `doGet` and `doPost` are currently implemented like this:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        App.checkDatabase(this);
        try {
            getImpl(request,response);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        App.checkDatabase(this);
        try {
            postImpl(request,response);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

And my `checkDatabase` method is implemented like this:

```
public static void checkDatabase(HttpServlet servlet)
{
    if(App.DATABASE == null) {
        App.DATABASE = "jdbc:sqlite:"+servlet.getServletContext().getRealPath(
            servlet.getServletContext().getInitParameter("DATABASE")
        );
    }
}
```

The way I'm doing things right now doesn't feel right. Surely there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would like to use a [`ServletContextListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to hook on webapp's startup and initialize applicationwide parameters. Here's a kickoff example assuming that you indeed have definied the path as a `<context-param>` with `<context-name>` of `DATABASE`:

```
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        String database = event.getServletContext().getInitParameter("DATABASE");
        // ...
    }

    // ...

}
```

Which you then map in `web.xml` as follows:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.Config</listener-class>
</listener>
```

You can if necessary store contextwide variables in `ServletContext` so that any servlet in turn can access it.

```
event.getServletContext().setAttribute("database", database);
```

...

```
Database database = (Database) getServletContext().getAttribute("database");
```

As Pascal hinted in his answer, you'd like to use under each JNDI for this. In that case, you can store the JNDI name as `<context-param>` and obtain/initialize the [`DataSource`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) (indirectly) in the `ServletContextListener` that way.

For more hints you may find [this basic example](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-use-in-jspservlet.html#WebappConfigurator) useful.

Comment: Thanks! This is much better than the way I was doing it.

Answer (score 2):

The right way would be to configure a connection pool at the server level and to use a datasource (either injected or obtained via JNDI) in your code to get a connection from the datasource.

If you add more details about your server, I could provide more guidance.

Comment: I'm using a Tomcat 6.14, and as an IDE Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.